# How do I import an Elliptical p256 public key using TSS.MSR (C++)

Tags: c++, tpm

I am trying to import a public key from another system into my system using Microsoft's MSR.TSS library (C++) in order to set up a Diffie-Hellman Key exchange.

However I get the following error:
"TPM Error - TPM_RC::SIZE: An attempt was made to join or substitute a drive for which a directory on the drive is the target of a previous substitute."

Here is my sample code:

```
            storagePrimaryHandle = MakeStoragePrimary();


            TPMT_PUBLIC eccTemplate(TPM_ALG_ID::SHA256,
                TPMA_OBJECT::decrypt | 
                TPMA_OBJECT::fixedParent | 
                TPMA_OBJECT::fixedTPM |
                TPMA_OBJECT::sensitiveDataOrigin | 
                TPMA_OBJECT::userWithAuth,
                NullVec,
                TPMS_ECC_PARMS(
                    TPMT_SYM_DEF_OBJECT(TPM_ALG_ID::_NULL, 0, TPM_ALG_ID::_NULL), 
                    TPMS_KEY_SCHEME_ECDH(TPM_ALG_ID::SHA256), 
                    TPM_ECC_CURVE::NIST_P256, 
                    TPMS_NULL_KDF_SCHEME()),
                TPMS_ECC_POINT()
            );


            //Import the public key
            //Create a vector with the 64 byte public key
            vector<BYTE> pubVector(publicKey, publicKey + publicKeyLength);

            //Indicate this is an uncompressed key
            pubVector.insert(pubVector.begin(), 1, 0x04);

            inPublic = _tpm.Create(storagePrimaryHandle, TPMS_SENSITIVE_CREATE(), eccTemplate, pubVector, vector<TPMS_PCR_SELECTION>());
```

Few things to note:
1) If I pass in an empty vector in place of "pubVector" it works
2) If I leave off the 0x04 (indicating an uncompressed public key), it still fails

My work is based off code at:
https://github.com/microsoft/TSS.MSR/tree/master/TSS.CPP/Samples

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:
The "Create" method creates a key from scratch, I needed the "LoadExternal" method to load a public key portion:

```
        //publicKey is a BYTE array of the p256 public key 64 bytes long (without the leading 04 = uncompressed)
        vector<BYTE> pubKeyX(publicKey, publicKey + 32);
        vector<BYTE> pubKeyY(publicKey+32, publicKey + 64);

        TPMT_PUBLIC eccTemplate(TPM_ALG_ID::SHA1,
            TPMA_OBJECT::decrypt | 
            TPMA_OBJECT::fixedParent | 
            TPMA_OBJECT::fixedTPM |
            TPMA_OBJECT::sensitiveDataOrigin | 
            TPMA_OBJECT::userWithAuth,
            NullVec,
            TPMS_ECC_PARMS(
                TPMT_SYM_DEF_OBJECT(TPM_ALG_ID::_NULL, 0, TPM_ALG_ID::_NULL), 
                TPMS_KEY_SCHEME_ECDH(TPM_ALG_ID::SHA256), 
                TPM_ECC_CURVE::NIST_P256, 
                TPMS_NULL_KDF_SCHEME()),
            TPMS_ECC_POINT(pubKeyX, pubKeyY)
        );

        pubHandle = _tpm.LoadExternal(TPMT_SENSITIVE::NullObject(), eccTemplate, TPM_HANDLE::FromReservedHandle(TPM_RH::_NULL));
```